# Autosuggestion for product code and name in Hybris storefronts search for a keyword

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby if a customer searches for any code or product name,if the content is there in the code or name,the product should be displayed in auto suggestion.How do I go about implementing this in Hybris?

Answer (score 0):

You can check SearchBoxComponent, it has these features in 6.6. I haven't got information for older versions.

Technically, JS trigger ajax call after few character entered and search mechanism working on solr.

You can get good detail about SOLR search here in hybris: https://hybrismart.com/2017/07/13/explaining-sap-hybrissolr-relevance-ranking-for-phrase-queries/